# Why doesn't this simple RegEx work with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

This is a really simple RegEx that isn't working, and I can't figure out why. According to [this](http://regexr.com?32pb9), it should work.

I'm on a Mac (OS X 10.8.2).

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
ZIP="software-1.3-licensetypeone.zip"
VERSION=$(sed 's/software-//g;s/-(licensetypeone|licensetypetwo).zip//g' <<< $ZIP)

echo $VERSION
```

**terminal**

```
$ sh script.sh
1.3-licensetypeone.zip
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [regex documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/re_format) for OS X 10.7.4 (but should apply to OP's 10.8.2), it is mentioned in the last paragraph that

> Obsolete (basic) regular expressions differ in several respects. `|` is an ordinary character and there is no equivalent for its functionality...
>
> ... The parentheses for nested subexpressions are `\(' and` )'...

`sed`, without any options, uses basic regular expression (BRE).

To use `|` in OS X or BSD's `sed`, you need to enable extended regular expression (ERE) via `-E` option, i.e.

```
sed -E 's/software-//g;s/-(licensetypeone|licensetypetwo).zip//g'
```

p/s: `\|` in BRE is a GNU extension.

---

Alternative ways to extract version number

1. chop-chop (parameter expansion)

   ```
   VERSION=${ZIP#software-}
   VERSION=${VERSION%-license*.zip}
   ```
2. `sed`

   ```
   VERSION=$(sed 's/software-\(.*\)-license.*/\1/' <<< "$ZIP")
   ```

   You don't necessarily have to match strings word-by-word with shell patterns or regex.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` works with simple regular expressions. You have to backslash parentheses and a vertical bar to make it work.

```
sed 's/software-//g;s/-\(licensetypeone\|licensetypetwo\)\.zip//g'
```

Note that I backslashed the dot, too. Otherwise, it would have matched any character.

Comment: Copied and pasted your line in there, but it still didn't work for me.

Comment: @curtisblackwell: Does your `sed` support `;` to separate commands? In some versions, multiple `-e` are needed: `sed -e 's///' -e 's///'`.

Comment: yeah, it supports multiple commands separated by `;`. I'm using that elsewhere.

Comment: @curtisblackwell: Does $ZIP contain whitespace? If it can, use `<<< "$ZIP"`.

Comment: no, it doesn't, but i should probably do use quotes in case it gets renamed.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in the shell, don't need sed, parameter expansion suffices:

```
shopt -s extglob
ZIP="software-1.3-licensetypeone.zip"
tmp=${ZIP#software-}
VERSION=${tmp%-licensetype@(one|two).zip}
```

With a recent version of bash (may not ship with OSX) you can use regular expressions

```
if [[ $ZIP =~ software-([0-9.]+)-licensetype(one|two).zip ]]; then
    VERSION=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

or, if you just want the 2nd word in a hyphen-separated string

```
VERSION=$(IFS=-; set -- $ZIP; echo $2)
```

Comment: Your last suggestion solves my problem. Thank you! However, I still don't understand why the RegEx doesn't work.

Comment: choroba explained it in his answer. Different programs (perl, sed, bash, etc) implement regular expressions in different ways. With sed, you need to escape the parentheses to give them their special meaning.

Comment: That sounds right, but even when I escaped them, it didn't work. Is it possible that my version of sed just doesn't support parentheses and/or pipes in regular expressions?

Comment: highly unlikely. Did you also escape the pipe? Read choroba's answer very carefully. You will also want to check `man sed` and (perhaps) `man ed` to learn about regexes implemented by sed.

Comment: I read his answer carefully. Re-read many times, because I thought it was correct. However, even copying and pasting the RegEx didn't work. I'll check man sed again, and look into ed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man sed | grep "regexp-extended" -A2
       -r, --regexp-extended

              use extended regular expressions in the script.
```